# Find closest instance of class

Tags: jquery

I have a list of comments with a reply option. When the reply button is clicked a form should appear below the comment.

HTML:

```
<div id="" class="comment">
    <div class="comment-message">Message
        <div class="information"> 
            <a id="" class="comment-reply" href="/comments/reply/"> Reply </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="test">Test</div>
```

CSS:

```
.test{display:none;}
```

jQuery:

```
 $('.comment-reply').live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $this = $(this);
    $this.closest('.test').toggle();
});
```

I have tried using the following:

```
$this.closest('.test').toggle();
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated , Thank you.

Comment: Explanation of `closest` function : *Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.*

Comment: By the way: there are several other issues with your code: `.live` is deprecated and `$this` is a global ( missing `var` keyword ).

Comment: One should always have [jQ API](http://api.jquery.com) in bookmarks `:)`

Comment: @freakish - Thanks for spotting the errors, all fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your html structure is same then you can try below,

```
$(this).closest('.comment').next().toggle()
```

In case if there are some elements between the `Reply` section and the `test` then use `.nextAll`

```
$(this).closest('.comment').nextAll('.test').toggle()
```

Comment: I'd say even do `.next('.test')` just incase!

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS I like `.next()` since I believe the html structure is same anyways.

Comment: $(this).closest('.comment').next().toggle() worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

If you have other closest elements and not only the comment with class `.test`, you need to make sure of getting the correct element doing the following:

```
$(this).closest('.comment').next('.test').toggle();
```